# Delete all paired bluetooth devices on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

I would like to delete paired bluetooth low energy devices with names that start with "ABC" on an iPhone programatically.

Comment: You cannot manipulate the paired devices through code. Only the user can do it through Bluetooth settings

Comment: This is bad. On Android, this can be done through code. I guess Apple tends to more things more restrictive.

Comment: I don't know whether it is "bad". Unless you need encryption you  don't bond BLE devices on iOS. If the device isn't bonded then it doesn't appear in the list of "paired" devices on iOS.